# How can I encode a json of a multiline result?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I try to encode my result in a json but it doesn't really work. When the query has more than one result than it doesn't work. When the result has only one line, than everything works fine.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['query'])) {
    $query = $_REQUEST['query'];
    $sql = mysqli_query ($db, "SELECT a, b FROM table WHERE a LIKE '%{$query}%' OR b LIKE '%{$query}%'");
    $array = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        $array[] = array (
            'label' => $row['a'].', '.$row['b'],
            'value' => $row['a'],
        );
    }
    //RETURN JSON ARRAY
    echo json_encode ($array); 
}
```

Comment: what error are you facing now? And can you show you $query data one and more than one

Comment: Apart from the possible sql injection, how does it not work?

Comment: When I execute this query in my database with the query = "test" than it has one result and it shows : [{"label":"test , testb","value":"test"}]..... But when I execute this query in my database with query = "cd" , it shows me over 100 results but the site is blank... If I echo the count of this array, it shows me the number of all results but the json is empty

Comment: Try using `print_r($array)` before array to see if your array has some value in it.

Comment: When I am using `print_r($array)`, it shows me every entry of the query in an array but with json_encode, the site is blank // EDIT: It works now, the array had some umlauts which has blocked the json_enocde function

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['query'])) {
    $query = $_REQUEST['query'];
    $sql = mysqli_query ($db, "SELECT a, b FROM table WHERE a LIKE '%{$query}%' OR b LIKE '%{$query}%'");
    $array = array();
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        $array[$i] = array (
            'label' => $row['a'].', '.$row['b'],
            'value' => $row['a'],
        );
        $i++;
    }
    //RETURN JSON ARRAY
    echo json_encode ($array); 
}
```

Comment: I've tried this code but the page is blank when there is more than one result

Comment: I have checked the code from my end and it is working fine